# how can I display the characters \t in a string?

Tags: c, literals, escaping

Evening all,
What would be the correct key sequence to display "\t" as a literal value, and not a text format?

My code is below...

Thanks a bunch.

```
main()
{

  int c;

  while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {

      if (c == '  ')
          c = "\t";
    putchar(c);
    }

}
```

So to clarify, I do not want to have a tabbed string, but instead display the characters \t.

Comment: By literal value, do you mean the string? Or the ascii integer value?

Answer (score 9):

You can escape a backslash with another backslash, i.e. `"\\t"`.

Incidentally, you're trying to assign a string (i.e. more than one character) to an `int`.  This doesn't make sense!

Answer (score 5):

Wouldn't you really want something like this instead?

```
if (c == '\t')
{
    printf("\\t");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Escape the backslash, thus `"\\t"`.

Answer (score 1):

To have a backslash in a character/string constant interpreted literally, you have to escape it with another backslash. Also, a single call to `putchar()` will not be enough since you have to print two characters. With this you get:

```
putchar('\\');
putchar('t');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the escape, as follows:

```
printf("\\t");
```

This will print `\t` as you want.

Comment: `System.out.println`, in **C**?

Comment: +1 Yes, it is not the same language, but the way to make it remains the same, that is, doubling the **`\\`** character. Instead of downvoting, perhaps simply tell the answerer that he's missing the right language.

Answer (score 0):

Actually "\t" requires two characters to display.

```
main()
{

  int c;

  while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {

      if (c == '  ') {
       putchar('\\');
       putchar('t');
      }
  }
```

would be one way of doing it.
}