# Is there any way to actually "print" \n?

Tags: c, escaping, literals, string-literals

In C, \n inside a string creates a new line, but is there any way to actually get \n to be printed?

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! It might be a surprise to you, but your question is off-topic here. We deal with computer *science* questions, not programming questions. Please see our [help on topic](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Your question might be on-topic on [SO].

Comment: All you have to do is escape the character with a backslash (\\). Computer Science is for computer science questions tho, ask this type of stuff on Stack Overflow!

Comment: Hilariously enough I just had to escape the literal backslash in the above comment!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can I display the characters \t in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4382775/how-can-i-display-the-characters-t-in-a-string)

Answer (score 3):

Use escape character `\`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char *a = "\\n";  //String in c
    printf("\\n , %s",a);
    //------^Escape Character
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
\n , \n
```

Comment: Better: `char *a = "\\n";`. The pointer to pointer isn't the appropriate type for printf's `"%s"`.

Comment: Yup! Changing it from array of string to just a string.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to do this--

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    fputs("\\n",stdout);
}
```

Is this helpfull??